# Hive groupby slower with partition

Tags: hive, partition

I partition my data in hive based on a column value(date). So each date has it's own directory in /warehouse. right now I have about 240 dates, and a total of 70 million records evenly distributed across dates.

I also create another table containing the same data that does not has partitions.

When I query both table with the same queries, the partitioned table does not always out-perform the unpartitioned one. More specifically, partitioned table is slower when executing query with group by.

```
select count(*) from not_partitioned_table where date > '2018-07-27' and date < '2018-08-27
```

This took 22.146 seconds, and the count is 7427366.

```
select count(*) from partitioned_table where date > '2018-07-27' and date < '2018-08-27
```

This took 22.723 seconds, and also returns 7427366 for count.

However when group by is added, partitioned table perform worse than un-partitioned table.

```
select count(*) from not_partitioned_table where dated > '2018-07-27' and date < '2018-08-27' group by col_name;
```

This took 39.733 seconds and 26,724 rows were returned.

```
select count(*) from partitioned_table where dated > '2018-07-27' and date < '2018-08-27' group by col_name;
```

This took 76.648 seconds seconds and 26,724 rows were returned.

Why is the partitioned table slower in this scenario?

**EDIT**

This is how I create my partitioned table:

```
CREATE TABLE all_ads_from_csv_partitioned3(
id STRING,
...
)
PARTITIONED BY(datedecoded STRING)
STORED AS ORC;
```

And under `2018-10-08 15:34 /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/partitioned_table/`, there are 240 directories(240 partitions), each has the format of `/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/partitioned_table/dated='the partitioned date'`, and each partition contains roughly 10 buckets.